# Problem with submitting form to google sheets

Tags: html

I have a problem with a form i created into my website and its connected with google sheets so if some one filled the form it should send the data to google sheet but i have a problem
If i used onclick to redirect users to another page it stops sending data to google sheet and if i don't use onclick it works perfect and send data to google sheet

My question is how can i redirect the users to another page and in the same time i can receive data into google sheet?

I searched a lot online to solve this problem but all the solutions don't work

Thanks in advance guys i hope to find the solution here

This is the code

```
<div class='form-style-6' id='opening'>
<h1>احجزي طلبك</h1>
<form id='openinge' name='submit-to-google-sheet'>
<input id='taher' name='name' placeholder='الاسم' type='text'/>
<input name='phone number' placeholder='رقم الهاتف' type='text'/>
<textarea name='address' placeholder='العنوان'/>


  <div>
        <select id='country' name='country' width='400'>
          <option value='نسيت تختار المقاس'>  --اختري المقاس--  </option>
          <option value='L'>L</option>
          <option value='M'>M</option>
          <option value='XL'>XL</option>
          <option value='XXL'>XXL</option>
          <option value='XXXL'>XXXL</option>
          <option value='XXXXL'>XXXXL</option>
          <option value='XXXXXL'>XXXXXL</option>
        </select>
    <select id='color' name='color' width='400'>
          <option value='نسيت تختار اللون'>  --اختري اللون--  </option>
          <option value='اللون الاسود'>اللون الاسود</option>
          <option value='اللون البيج'>اللون البيج</option>

        </select>
      </div>


<input id='submit-form' onclick='window.location.href = &apos;https://spanxkuwaitconfirm.blogspot.com&apos;;' type='submit' value='ارسلي الطلب'/>
</form>
</div>




    <script>

  const scriptURL = &#39;https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx5dGRCKt1w_FHZZcm5ktE5Ada3QPVu6RvU/exec&#39;
  const form = document.forms[&#39;submit-to-google-sheet&#39;]

  form.addEventListener(&#39;submit&#39;, e =&gt; {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: &#39;POST&#39;, body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response =&gt; console.log(&#39;Success!&#39;, response))
      .catch(error =&gt; console.error(&#39;Error!&#39;, error.message))
  })


</script>.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to do the redirect after the data was submitted to the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script.
- You have already confirmed that your Web Apps worked fine.

#### Modification point:

- In your script, how about removing `onclick` of `<input id='submit-form' onclick='window.location.href = "https://spanxkuwaitconfirm.blogspot.com"'` and putting `window.location.href = "https://spanxkuwaitconfirm.blogspot.com"` to Javascript?

When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
<input id='submit-form' onclick='window.location.href = &apos;https://spanxkuwaitconfirm.blogspot.com&apos;;' type='submit' value='ارسلي الطلب'/>
</form>
</div>




    <script>

  const scriptURL = &#39;https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx5dGRCKt1w_FHZZcm5ktE5Ada3QPVu6RvU/exec&#39;
  const form = document.forms[&#39;submit-to-google-sheet&#39;]

  form.addEventListener(&#39;submit&#39;, e =&gt; {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: &#39;POST&#39;, body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response =&gt; console.log(&#39;Success!&#39;, response))
      .catch(error =&gt; console.error(&#39;Error!&#39;, error.message))
  })


</script>
```

To:

```
    <input id='submit-form' type='submit' value='ارسلي الطلب'/>  <!-- Modified -->
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx5dGRCKt1w_FHZZcm5ktE5Ada3QPVu6RvU/exec';
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet'];
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(scriptURL, {method: "POST", body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        window.location.href = "https://spanxkuwaitconfirm.blogspot.com";  // <--- Added
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error.message));
  });
</script>
```

- In this modification, after the data was submitted, `window.location.href = "https://spanxkuwaitconfirm.blogspot.com";` is run.

#### Note:

- In your script, the numerical character references are used. So in this modification, I modified it for higher readability. So please be careful this. When you are required to use the numerical character references, please modify above modified script.